# how to increase the maximum size of the pool /dev/random

Tags: linux

Currently, I have a max size of 4096 bytes :

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize           
4096
```

I need to generate many PGP keys and I really need to use /dev/random
for a security reason.

I have been looking for some kernel flags about this pool size, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: 4096 bits, not bytes. See http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Entropy_and_randomness

Comment: As this question was asked nearly 8 years ago, things have changed. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704743/241396 for modern implementation of `kernel.random.poolsize`.

Answer (score 2):

To set writeable kernel parameters you can use sysctl interactively:

`sysctl kernel.random.poolsize=8192`

or you can echo the value to the /proc filesystem:

`echo 8192 > /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize`

To make the changes effective after boot you can add a line to  `/etc/sysctl.conf` (before boot you can usually pass the parameter in the bootloader on the `kernel` line):

`kernel.random.poolsize=8192`

After doing the former you can run `sysctl -p` for changes to be effective.  This is assuming that the parameter is writeable or can be increased beyond the current value.  If it isn't then you will have to rebuild the kernel or find an alternative.

However, your issue may be in being able to fill up the pool quickly enough for your needs.  You might want to look into [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/)

This type of question may attract more attention at [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com) and I was recently looking at this question on [Entropy](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89/feeding-dev-random-entropy-pool) which you may find of interest.

Comment: It seems that the /proc file is not writable (I have a standard linux kernel 4.1.3), do you know the flags to change in the kernel configs ?

Comment: This doesn't work. `sysctl: setting key "kernel.random.poolsize": No such file or directory`; `/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize: Permission denied`

Comment: This solution only works on linux 2.4.x (as the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/4/random) clearly says: "Linux 2.6: [`/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize`] is read-only, and gives the size of the entropy pool in bits. It contains the value `4096`.")

Answer (score 2):

To change the size of the pool(s) in recent kernels (2.6 and later) you would need to patch and recompile the kernel, since the configuration is hardcoded:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/27db64f65f1be2f2ee741a1bf20d8d13d62c167f/drivers/char/random.c#L284-L287

---

An obligatory note: the size of the entropy pool is not really relevant for your use case. It's instead much more important how fast the pool is replenished. But changing the size of the entropy pool does not affect how fast the pool is replenished, so there's little to no point in increasing the size of the pool.

If, as you state, you **really really really** have to generate **lots** of keys then you should get a dedicated hardware RNG, because `/dev/random` is likely not a good pick.

Also, if you haven't done so, have a read of https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ that, while not 100% accurate, gives you some insights about the differences (or lack thereof) between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` - as it is quite likely that the most correct solution for you would be "use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`" (that is, by the way, what `openssl` does by default; more precisely it uses `getrandom` in non-blocking mode)

Answer (score 1):

Note `/proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize` is read-only since Linux Kernel 2.6.

Moreover Linux Kernel `5.10.119` changed the meaning of `poolsize` constant, the value is even lower on newer kernels:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/poolsize
256
```

But it doesn't mean that the entropy pool would be smaller, see [kernel 5.10.119 caused the values of /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail and poolsize to be 256"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704743/34514)  for details.